# Open the sublime as an administrator

Tags: sublime-text

I was looking for a way to run sublime text right from the desktop (without using the terminal) as an administrator. So far so good, I modified the file sublime_text.desktop with a text editor, called the command `sudo -H` after the exec command, like this:

Before:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Sublime Text
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text %F
Terminal=false
MimeType=text/plain;
Icon=sublime-text
Categories=TextEditor;Development;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=Window;Document;

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=New Window
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text -n
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Document]
Name=New File
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text --command new_file
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

after:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Sublime Text
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose
Exec= sudo -H /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text %F
Terminal=false
MimeType=text/plain;
Icon=sublime-text
Categories=TextEditor;Development;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=Window;Document;

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=New Window
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text -n
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Document]
Name=New File
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text --command new_file
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

and until it worked, when I click on the sublime it opens normally as root administrator, but it opens only with the files I left open on it, its packages and modifications are reset. Could someone tell me a method to get around this problem? would help me a lot.

Comment: The packages and modifications are reset every time you open the application?

Comment: Yes, when opening Sublime (after I modified the file sublime_text.desktop) it simply opens as if finished if installed. I just want to make this change so that I can create files directly from within the sublime, and a folder where the files will be required root permission.

Comment: You will probably want to copy the `.config/sublime-text-3` directory from your home directory to `/root` then, as running things with `sudo` does not necessarily mean using the same `PATH` information.